VSCode terminal activates virtual environment but still uses wrong Python interpreter
I use mise to manage Python installations and have poetry set up to create virtual environments in the project folder. When I open a project in VSCode, it seems to select the correct Python interpreter e.g. Python 3.12.2 ('.venv': Poetry) ./.venv/bin/python. But if I run
which python
/Users/user/.local/share/mise/installs/python/3.11/bin/python

it shows the global Python, not the one from the virtual environment.
However, it errors if I try running in the VSCode terminal
poetry shell
Virtual environment already activated: /Users/user/my-project/.venv

and will not be able to find any packages installed using poetry add
If I try
deactivate
zsh: permission denied: deactivate

but if I run
source ./.venv/bin/activate
/Users/user/my-project/.venv/bin/python

everything works the way it should! But it's frustrating to have to run source when VSCode seems to already be activating the virtual environment and using the correct interpreter. What am I missing/misunderstanding here?
Edit: Using poetry shell works fine outside of VSCode e.g. in WezTerm
which python
/Users/user/my-project/.venv/bin/python


Can you try setting false to "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment ? There might be incorrect activation of your environment upon terminal creation in VS Code
